# Add and Remove Class On Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on an HTML page with a small navigation that starts out about halfway down the page. I want the navigation bar to stick to the top of the page (become fixed) when it reaches the top of the page. My attempt looked like this:

The script:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var header = $(".clearHeader");
    $(window).scroll(function() {    
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 100) {
            header.removeClass('scrollHeader').addClass("fixedHeader");
        } else {
            header.removeClass("fixedHeader").addClass('scrollHeader');
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="scrollHeader">
            <div class="row" style="background:#444;">
            <div class="container">
            <a href="#"><div class="col-sm-3 smallNav">
            Perks
            </div></a>
            <a href="#"><div class="col-sm-3 smallNav">
            Growth
            </div></a>
            <a href="#"><div class="col-sm-3 smallNav">
            Technology
            </div></a>
            <a href="#"><div class="col-sm-3 smallNav">
            Apply
            </div></a>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

The CSS:

```
.scrollHeader { position: relative !important;}
.fixedHeader {position: fixed !important; }
```

Nevertheless, this code doesn't work. Any suggestions? I have jQuery 1.9.1 loaded. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5d7ymoc0/1/)

Comment: Please add a fiddle.

Comment: @NabilKadimi added a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5d7ymoc0/

Comment: your markup does not seem to contain any element with a class `clearHeader` while you seem to be using it in your JS, please rectify this

Answer (score 1):

Just from a quick look, I am not sure if you are targeting the right object at the start of your code.

```
var header = $(".clearHeader");
```

But in your HTML, nothing is of class "clearHeader", so this would not work. Perhaps changing it to

```
var header = $(".scrollHeader");
```

Would do the trick?

Edit: also adding top:0px; to your fixedHeader class will make the nav stick to the top of the page.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5d7ymoc0/2/

BONUS super smooth nav scroll action: http://jsfiddle.net/5d7ymoc0/4/

Comment: Close... but that would at some point leave the div without any class, which I assume child classes may get some styles for. Need to keep one as the "base" class, and have the others as position modifiers. See my answer - simply adding a class in the markup worked fine for me

Comment: Although he could just not remove the scrollHeader class, and only add/remove the fixed class and then this solution works fine

Comment: Hey, changed the .clearHeader to .scrollHeader and nothing changed. Check the fiddle I added to the post.

Comment: True, your solution is better. Either way the issue is with the targeting of the header, so should be fixed :)

Comment: I think it is working, but your position fixed is being placed out of window. Try either solution and also add top:0px; to your fixedHeader class.

Comment: @LewisCarey: _“but your position fixed is being placed out of window. […] add top:0px; to your fixedHeader class”_ – that is the solution, you should modify your answer to say that.

Answer (score 0):

Is `$('.clearHeader')` supposed to be `$('.scrollHeader')` ?

Is so...

```
$(function() {

    navPos = $(".scrollHeader").position().top;

    $(window).scroll(function() {    
        if(navPos>0 && $(window).scrollTop()>navPos) {              
            $(".navbar").addClass("navbar-fixed-top");
        } else {
            $(".navbar").removeClass("navbar-fixed-top");
        }

        if (scroll >= ) {
            header.removeClass('scrollHeader').addClass("fixedHeader");
        } else {
            header.removeClass("fixedHeader").addClass('scrollHeader');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the header to stick to the top on scroll I believe this is what you want.

example jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5d7ymoc0/3/

change to javascript:

```
           $(function() {

             $(window).scroll(function() {    

        //fix the header to the top
      $(".smallNav").css({"position":"fixed","top":"0px"});



       });
        });
```

change to css:

```
   scrollHeader { position: relative !important;}
   .fixedHeader {position: fixed !important; }
   .smallNav {background: #333; color: #fff !important;padding: 10px;font-size: 20px; text-align:      center; }
   .wrapper {height: 2000px;}
```