# How to make a header fixed after scrolling past it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Want to make header become fixed to the top of the page after scrolling it to the top. Tried looking at other stackoverflow answers but can't seem to get my code to do what I want it to.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
        <title>test</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "header">
            <div id = "contents">
                <img src ="unnamed.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul class ="nav">
            <li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="news.asp">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.asp">About</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id = "page">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body, #header {
    width:100%;
    height:85%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#header {
    z-index:-1;
    box-shadow:0px 1px 15px black;
}
#page {
    margin-top:-20px;
    background-color:white;
}
#header #contents {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:-1;
    left:50%;
    top:30%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align:center;
}
.nav {
    text-align:center;
    background-color: rgb(233,204,148);
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align:center;
}
.nav li {
    display:inline;
}
.nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    padding: 30px 35px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right:20px;
}

.nav li a:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color:rgb(233,204,148); 
}
```

Comment: this won't work with just CSS. You will need some JavaScript to check if the element has reached the top when scrolling. In the future this will be possible with `position: sticky`, but that is only implemented in Chrome and Safari.

Comment: below post has answer may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26940990/add-and-remove-class-on-scroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <div id = "header">
      <div id = "contents">
         <img src ="unnamed.jpg">
      </div>
   </div>
   <ul class ="nav" id="navBar">
     <li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="news.asp">News</a></li>
     <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
     <li><a href="about.asp">About</a></li>
   </ul>
   <div id = "page">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae suscipit laboriosam nobis eveniet? Atque asperiores, sunt, ad ducimus corrupti ipsam possimus eum deleniti ipsa saepe quasi dolores? Numquam ipsam, cum.</p>
   </div>


$(window).scroll(function function_name (argument) {
            if($(window).scrollTop() > 250){
               $(".nav").addClass('fixedClass')
            }
            else{
               $(".nav").removeClass('fixedClass')
            }
         })


html, body, #header {
    width:100%;
    height:85%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;

}

#header {
    z-index:-1;
    box-shadow:0px 1px 15px black;

}
#page {
    margin-top:-20px;
    background-color:white;
}
#header #contents {

    left:50%;
    top:30%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align:center;
}
.nav {
    text-align:center;
    background-color: rgb(233,204,148);
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align:center;
}
.nav li {
    display:inline;

}
.nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    padding: 30px 35px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right:20px;
}
.fixedClass{
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
}
```

You need to check the scroll position to notify the header when to have a fixed position.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this below code to make a header fixed after scrolling past it :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      .affix {
          top: 0;
          width: 100%;
      }

      .affix + .container-fluid {
          padding-top: 70px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#F44336;color:#fff;height:500px;padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">
      <img src ="img/0.JPG" style="height: 500px;width: 100%;">
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="500">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Basic Topnav</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid" style="height:1000px">
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
      <h1>Some text to enable scrolling</h1>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: And one advice, don't use remote js file .As you used in `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>` . For this You download that file and store locally and use it.

Comment: Thanks man, will do :) also just curious but does using a remote file have negative effects on page loading or something?

Comment: Yes , it will sometime gives you loading problem

Comment: @TaneTurner best Practice while deploying the code is use both local and remote. Keep Remote in fallback if Local file fails loading then it will look for CDN path. Performance wise local file will load fast.

Comment: @Krishna9960 Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
<title>test</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.appear/0.3.3/jquery.appear.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id = "header">
<div id = "contents">
<img src ="unnamed.jpg">
</div>
</div>
<ul class ="nav nav-relative">
  <li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="news.asp">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.asp">About</a></li>
</ul>
<div id = "page">

</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if(($('#header').is(':appeared'))){
      $('.nav').removeClass('nav-fixed').addClass('nav-relative')
    }
    else {
      $('.nav').removeClass('nav-relative').addClass('nav-fixed')
    }
})
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
</body>
  </html>
```

#### CSS

```
html, body, #header {
    width:100%;
    height:85%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;

}

#header {
    z-index:-1;
    box-shadow:0px 1px 15px black;

}
#page {
    margin-top:-20px;
    background-color:white;
}
#header #contents {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:-1;
    left:50%;
    top:30%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align:center;
}
.nav {
    text-align:center;
    background-color: rgb(233,204,148);
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align:center;
}
.nav-fixed {
  position: fixed;
    top:0px;
    width: 100%;
}
.fixedClass{
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
}
.nav li {
    display:inline;

}
.nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    padding: 30px 35px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right:20px;
}

.nav li a:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color:rgb(233,204,148);
}
```

Comment: But what does this do?

Comment: this is more generic.It checks whether the header is visible and based on ti it decides nav should be fixed or not